# Unity countdown with scenemanager

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Basically it is the following: I have 2 codes, 1 that serves to reset the level when I shoot the ball:

```
public Player player;
public float resetTimer = 5f;

void Update () {
        if (player.holdingBall == false) {
            resetTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
            if (resetTimer <= 0) {
                SceneManager.LoadScene ("Game");
            }
```

And this one is a timer that goes to an end game screen

```
void Start () 
 {
  timerSeconds = GetComponent<Text> ();
 }
 
 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update () 
 {
  timer -= Time.deltaTime;
  timerSeconds.text = timer.ToString("f0");
  if (timer <= 0) 
  {
   Application.LoadLevel (LevelToLoad);
  }
 }
```

The problem is this: when I throw the ball after 5 seconds the level resets but the timer also returns to 30 but I didn't want it to reset. What should i do? Should i have brought the two codes  together or ...

Comment: When a scene is loaded all objects are re-loaded, meaning all their fields will go back to their initial value. If you want the timer to persist between scene loads you could consider making it `static`?

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: lol it was simplier than i though i just added a static float timer = 5f ty